# How to structure my user data in firebase securely

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures, nosql, firebase-security

I am building an application with users and companies. This is how I'm currently structuring the data:

```
  "users" : {
    "userid1" : {
      "email" : "oops@gmail.com",
      "id": "userid1",
      "type": "user"
    },
    "userid2" : {
      "email" : "not@gmail.com",
      "id": "userid2",
      "type": "company"
    },
```

I would like companies to edit their own profiles and be visible to users. Users should be able to rate companies. These are my database rules:

```
{
"rules": {
  ".write": "auth.uid != null",
  ".read": "auth.uid != null"
 }
}
```

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree and of your rules in the question. Please replace that with the actual rules and JSON as text, the latter of which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON and rules as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and rules, and use then in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, do you have any suggestions regarding my question?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like companies to edit their own profiles and be visible to users.

With your current structure, the simplest way to implement that is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "data.child('type').val() === 'company'",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && data.child('type').val() === 'company'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I highly recommend checking out some other [questions about the Firebase Realtime Database and security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database+firebase-security-rules?sort=votes&pageSize=50) to learn more about do's, don'ts and common pitfalls.